# atop configuration file location on CentOS 7.x

Tags: linux, centos7, process

I have installed atop on my server using yum, its started and running. however I cannot find the configuration file on the server to tweak the settings.

All mentions of it online point to `/etc/atop/` however there is no folder/files at that location.

Has anyone seen the same behaviour? I want it to poll more frequently.

Thanks

Comment: Hint, you can call the rpm command with the "-qc" option to get a list of a configuration files for the given package

Answer (score 2):

In centos 7x, see

```
 /etc/sysconfig/atop
```

Answer (score 1):

according to the [man page](http://www.atoptool.nl/download/man_atop-1.pdf), in the FILES section:

```
/etc/atoprc
Configuration file containing system-wide default values.
```

So I guess you should look there. You also have a `~/.atoprc` file with your personal preferences.

Maybe interesting to note, the `/etc/atoprc` file is not automatically created. If you install atop from EPEL repo, it does not add the atoprc manpage either.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for both those files/locations but neither of them exist.  Im not sure if its just a case of creating them and restarting atop to see if they get picked up. I thought it had not installed properly.