# How to change interval of atop log?

Tags: centos7, top, atop

My system is centos 7.4 with atop 2.3.0

I want to change atop log interval from default `600` to `300`,then I `vi /usr/share/atop/atop.daily` as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

CURDAY=`date +%Y%m%d`
LOGPATH=/var/log/atop
BINPATH=/usr/bin
PIDFILE=/var/run/atop.pid
INTERVAL=600                            # interval 10 minutes

# support /etc/sysconfig/atop
source /etc/sysconfig/atop
```

I notice `source /etc/sysconfig/atop`,then I open `/etc/sysconfig/atop`:

```
CURDAY=`date +%Y%m%d`
# Log files path
LOGPATH=/var/log/atop
# Binaries path
BINPATH=/usr/bin
# PID File
PIDFILE=/var/run/atop.pid
# interval (default 10 minutes)
INTERVAL=600
```

Both files has `INTERVAL=600`,which file should be revised?

Comment: I assume as `INTERVAL` in `/etc/sysconfig/atop` is getting sourced _after_ the initial definition that the latter in `/etc/sysconfig/atop` would take precedence. Some tools use the first found directive, some tools use the last set directive (it is the default config file for atop, too). Also have a look here: https://serverfault.com/questions/790489/atop-configuration-file-location-on-centos-7-x

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "LOGINTERVAL=60" >> /etc/sysconfig/atop
```

For Centos 7.

If you have a look at /usr/share/atop/atop.daily, it expects variable $LOGINTERVAL to be overriden